# Why is my nether portal sending me to a new one I didn't build (exiting the nether)? (Xbox One Edition, last update ever made to that edition)

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

This is referring back to an old version of Minecraft, specifically Xbox One edition (XBOE). I got this version of Minecraft right after the 1.12 update, so I'm not sure how long this has been around for, but has lasted to the very last update of XBOE. My brother and I built a single portal in the overworld, went to the nether, explored, and came back through, but it spwaned a new portal about 300 blocks away, despite us only building one portal. This happened no matter how you entered the portal, or part of the portal you went through. It would always send you to the portal several hundred blocks away. Has this happened to anyone else? (I no longer have access to this world, as it is not on my account, but rather my brother's; which he forgot how to sign into, but it is not deleted.)

Edit: This has happened to me one other time on a world in Bedrock Edition, though I deleted that world